# SQL Query distinct rows + minimum value

Tags: sql, distinct

Sorry for being noob, but need some help in creating this query:

table

```
id  | C  | S  | T   
--- |--- |--- |---  
1   |C1  |S1  |DA   
2   |C1  |S1  |DA   
3   |C1  |S1  |DB   
4   |C2  |S3  |DA   
5   |C1  |S2  |DC
```

Need to show first row for each unique C (with smallest id)

So end result will look like (C1 and C2 are unique, C1 shows only first line as ID is 1):

```
    id  | C  | S  | T   
    --- |--- |--- |---  
    1   |C1  |S1  |DA   
    4   |C2  |S3  |DA
```

Can you please help?
I tried to play around distinct and inner join but cant get any good results.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `row_number()` for this:

```
select id, c, s, t
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by c order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) function with partition by you will be able to create groups which will give row numbers to each group based on values in C columns starting with `1 to n`. To select the first row you can use `RowNum = 1`;

```
With TableCTE
As
(
SELECT id, C, S, T, ROW_NUMBER()(Partition by C Order by Id) as RowNum
From TableName
)

SELECT * FROM TableCtE 
WHERE RowNum = 1;
```